# single page with multiple partials and forms

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What is the best practice for this:

I have a list of partials on one page. Each page has a form on it to save the data of the partial.

I do this like this on the main page:

```
    @foreach (var taak in Model)
{
   @Html.Action("DetailTaak", "Checklist", new { trouwTaakId = taak.Id }) 
}
```

Then the controller is this (where the data is filled):

```
        public  ActionResult DetailTaak(int trouwTaakId)
    {
        DTO.Trouw.TrouwTaak viewModel;
        viewModel = _themaService.GetTrouwTaakByTrouwTaakId(trouwTaakId);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The page gets build and the list is completed. Now when I want to save a partial using this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DetailTaak", "Checklist",  FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal col-md-12", role = "form", id = @Model.Id }))
            {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        ...
            }
```

It works but what do I do so the mainpage doesn't have to be reloaded ? This is the post code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DetailTaak(DTO.Trouw.TrouwTaak model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.SaveSuccess = "Je instellingen zijn opgeslagen";
        }
        return View("DetailTaak", model);
    }
```

With this post code I go to the DetailTaak page instead of staying on the main page and just updating the partial.
I am doing something wrong but I don't know which way to go.

kind regards

Comment: If you want to post but stay on the same page you will need to use ajax.

Comment: Ok I did it with ajax and that worked!
Cheers